# Using Scala applicative to convert List[Object] to case class

Tags: scala, deserialization, applicative

I am writing a Scala [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) application that uses [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/) as a back-end database.

When I query Datomic, it returns "rows" as `java.util.List`s of `List`s of `java.lang.Object`s. For example:

```
[
  [ "Joe", "1970-04-15" ],
  [ "Mary", "1975-06-01" ]
]
```

I would like to convert these to case classes in the most Scala-idiomatic way possible.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
import org.joda.time._
case class Person(name: String, dateOfBirth: LocalDate)

// assuming the query returns 1 row, get the row List
val row = result.iterator.next  // e.g.: [ "Joe", "1970-04-15" ]
User(row.get(0).asInstanceOf[String],
     LocalDate.parse(row.get(1).asInstanceOf[String]))
```

That's sort of ugly and error-prone.

Is there a way to use applicative functors to achieve the same thing? Are applicative functors the best way to do this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result.collect {case name::date::Nil => Person(name.toString, LocalDate.parse(date.toString)}
          // or case List(name,date) => ...
```

Comment: This actually answers my question, but I think I'm going to use the technique described by @wheaties.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good library written by Pellucid called [Datomisca](https://github.com/pellucidanalytics/datomisca) which bridges the gap between Datomic(Clojure) and Scala in a type safe manner. Take a look how they do their [conversions](http://pellucidanalytics.github.io/datomisca/doc/features.html#features-scalatypes):

```
val entity = database.entity(entityId)
val name   = entity.as[String](person / "name")
val age    = entity.as[Long](person / "age")
```

which is taken right out from their website.

Comment: Sweet! I think that's exactly what I need.

Comment: @Ralph yeah, it's always good when someone writes a library for you to do exactly what you want. I tend to write square wheels.